# A Basic Guide To Starting With Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am confused to were to start when creating my app.

When I click the add button I am wanting to show a form - Do I append a div to that button?

How do I attack this?

**Code:**

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div classa="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Birthday Reminders</h1>
    </div>
       <p>Data Here</p>
  </div>

  <div id="push"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused; I don't see any AngularJS code. Are you manually bootstrapping your app?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I have not written any code yet as im not sure were to start.  I am using the Twitter BS

Comment: great place to start is go through tutorial in docs

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning

Comment: W3Schools Manual is a good way to start: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Okay, from the top! :-)

First, you have to tell AngularJS somewhere that you're using it. The `body` tag is as good a place as any: `<body ng-app="myApp">`. [This](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp) tells AngularJS to use a module called `myApp` as the root of your application. So let's define that now:

```js
// app.js

var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );
```

The second argument is an array of dependencies. We won't worry about that now. So now we have a [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module). AngularJS is an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework, so we also need to define a controller somewhere. Let's add this to our `app.js` file:

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope ) {
  // we control our app from here
});
```

The `$scope` variable is how we glue our controller logic to the view. Speaking of the view, we have to tell AngularJS to use this controller someplace. Let's edit the `body` tag once more:

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Boom! Our app works. So now AngularJS is all set up and working, so we can tackle your question.

You want to make something appear on a certain action. There's a directive for that called [`ngShow`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow). It will show whatever's inside of it when the condition is true:

```html
<form ng-show="visible">
```

What is `visible`? That's an [expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). In this case, it's just a variable. Defined where? On our scope!

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope ) {
  $scope.visible = false;
});
```

Okay, so now it starts out as `false`; how do we change it to `true` when we click a button? There's a directive for that called [`ngClick`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick) that also takes an expression:

```html
<a class="btn" ng-click="visible = true">Show the Form</a>
```

In this case, our expression changes the `visible` variable to `true`. And immediately, the form is shown! Here's a completed Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kt4dR2tiTkShVYWCqQle?p=preview

Welcome to AngularJS!

---

Here are some supplemental resources you should grok:

- The Tutorial: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
- The Guide: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/
- Migrating from jQuery: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/259038)

And also join us on the [Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular)! We're good people.

Comment: wow thanks Josh - I have just watched http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4 so I am getting into the mind frame

Comment: John's videos are great. Also check out the [AngularJS YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/angularjs) and the [Egghead.io](http://egghead.io/) tutorials.

Comment: hey i am understanding the concept very nice but.. were and how to test my example .. i never came across this in my video tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the quickstart; especially for the lazy people like me :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just starting to test out Angular. I've only been using it for about a week now. Things are pretty cool when you get realize how they work. Wish there were better/more documentation on it though.
I drew up a quick [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3CVEJ/32/) what it sounded like you were looking for. Let me know if that's somewhat of what you were looking for. Should work completely.

```
<div ng-controller="bdayCtrl">
<h3>Birthday Reminders</h3>
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="bday in bdays">
        <td>{{bday.name}}</td>
        <td>{{bday.date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a class="btn" ng-click="visible = true">Add new</a><br>

<form class="form-horizontal" ng-show="visible" ng-submit="newDate()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="bdayname" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="bdaydate" placeholder="Birthdate">
    <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Add</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And your script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function bdayCtrl($scope) {
$scope.bdays = [{
        "name": "Jamal",
        "date": "Jan 1, 1980"
}, {
        "name": "Paula",
        "date": "Jan 1, 2000"
}, {
        "name": "Damon",
        "date": "Jun 30, 1800"
}];

$scope.newDate = function () {
    $scope.bdays.push({name:$scope.bdayname, date:$scope.bdaydate});
    $scope.bdayname = '';
    $scope.bdaydate = '';
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a simple and a more involved example of creating Angular applications with no prior knowledge:

[Formatting an html element](http://www.angularbasics.co.uk/?Id=4)

and

[Adding a data edit facility](http://www.angularbasics.co.uk/?Id=8)

They should help provide easy familiarisation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers here should be self-contained, which means they should make sense and be useful even if any links in them break. Unfortunately this answer will not be very useful if those links break. Perhaps you can **edit it to fix this**? Later, when you have enough reputation to comment, you can give links like this as comments.